# how to fix my symmetry sculpt mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting, sculpt

I have an issue with my symmetry in sculpt mode. at the beginning everything was working well but Idk, maybe I did something wrong by joining meshes or what but I can't find how to fix my mirror symmetry problem as you can see on the pics :/

[image]
[image]

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: if you've lost the symmetry you could go in Edit mode and Mesh > Symmetrize, choose the axis in the Operator box, then see if it works again?

Comment: I have tried that but this didn't work :/